# OLS as estimator

Tags: regression, time-series, least-squares, macroeconomics

we've been given following question, but have some trouble getting started, can anyone help out?

$\pi_{t}=\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2} u_{t}+\alpha_{3} \pi_{t+1 | t}^{e}+\eta_{t}, \quad t=1,2, \ldots, T$

We have that $\pi_{t+1}$  is inflation rate measured as the change in consumer prices from the year before. $u_{t}$ is is the unemployment rate as a percentage of the labour force measuring the business cycle.
$\pi_{t+1 | t}^{e}$ is the expected inflation in the next period, t+1, given the information available at the beginning of period t. $\eta_{t}$ measures other things affecting inflation, and it is assumed to be i.i.d.

First, assume that we have a survey measure of expected inflation
$\pi_{t+1 | t}^{\text { survey }}=\pi_{t+1 | t}^{e}+v_{t}$

where $v_{t}$ is a measurement error, uncorrelated with $u_{t}$ and $\eta_{t}$. Further We have  is i.i.d. with $(_)=0$ and $(^2_)=^2$

$v_{t}$ is i.i.d.

Can you use OLS to estimate the: $\beta=\left(\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \alpha_{3}\right)^{\prime}$
why? why not?

We're considering to make a walk trough of the assumptions, considering a consistent estimator (weak stationarity, dependence and predetermindness).

Comment: Why do you have *consistency* in the title if the body does not contain anything about to that?

Comment: I guess we wanted to discuss if it could be used, by looking at the assumptions for a consistent estimator. Including weak stationarity, dependence and predetermindnes.

Comment: Great. Would you mind including this explicitly in your post and perhaps updating the title slightly to make it more informative?

Comment: do you know the variances? or are you estimating them as well? my first though was you should have a 2-dimensional regression with $\pi^{e}_{t+1|t}$ on the left hand side and $\pi^{survey}_{t+1|t}$ added onto the right hand side predictors - ie "unknowns" = "linear combination of knowns" + "error"

Comment: Of course yes - I'll add that as well. We have $\eta_{t}$ is i.i.d. with $E(\eta_{t})=0$ and $E(\eta_{t}^2)=\sigma^2$